# How to form complete URLs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, url, replace

I'm trying to create a small system where people can fill in info, including their web site address. Only, some people will enter "www.example.com", some will enter "http://www.example.com", and some will enter "example.com".

What is the most clean way to:

- Validate al URLs, in the sense that they all are including http:// so when I click on it I get redirected correctly, and also
- For the visible text on the link, what's the easiest way to get the version without http://?

I could of course go crazy with some conditional text replacements, but there has to be a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I will to this way that I check that address begins with `http(s)://` if not then add it. Don't do anything with `example.com` and `www.example.com` because it can destroy whole address.

So you can write:

```
url = 'http://' + url unless url =~ /\Ahttps?:\/\//
```

Comment: To put it more clearly, `www.blah.com` and `blah.com` could be two totally different addresses; don't do anything with that. Do add `http://`, but *only if no scheme already exists* (what if they entered `https://`?).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a gem for this -- there's no reason to try to write all this yourself.

Here's one that may fit your needs. There may be others, but this one seems useful and has a decent following:

https://github.com/conickal/validates_url_format_of